# sum() or other method to count TRUEs in a subset of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, logical-operators

I have an 5000 x 8000 dataframe of mostly logical values. I would like to count TRUE values in various rectangular portions. The perfect solution would look like this:

```
features.total <- sum(df[ , 651:8500])
```

Alas, that doesn't work.  Here are some examples to play with:

```
aa <- bb <- cc <- dd <- rep.int(FALSE,4)
df1 <- data.frame(aa, bb, cc, dd, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df1[2:3,2:3] <- TRUE

ww <- xx <- yy <- zz <- rep.int(0,4)
df2 <- data.frame(ww, xx, yy, zz, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2[2:3,2:3] <- 1

v0 <- c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)
v1 <- as.vector(df1[2, ])
v2 <- c(0, 1, 1, 0)
```

sum() works fine with the ones you'd expect, but fails with others:

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :    only defined on a data frame with all
>   numeric variables

- `sum(v0)`  works fine
- `sum(v1)`  fails
- `sum(v2)`  works fine
- `sum(df1)` fails
- `sum(df2)` works fine

Logical objects are smaller and simpler. Is there an alternative approach that would allow me to stick with TRUE and FALSE, but fulfill the need to add up regions?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the manual unlisting and converting to `matrix` as proposed by jay we can also use some of the R-functions specifically designed to work for `data.frames` e.g. `rowSums()` and `colSums()`. These functions work on each row/column of a `data.frame` therefore implicitly converting their arguments to vectors, for which sum is defined. After this is done for each row/column we can just sum over the result to get the total sum.

```
aa <- bb <- cc <- dd <- rep.int(FALSE,4)
df1 <- data.frame(aa, bb, cc, dd, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df1[2:3,2:3] <- TRUE

ww <- xx <- yy <- zz <- rep.int(0,4)
df2 <- data.frame(ww, xx, yy, zz, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2[2:3,2:3] <- 1

v0 <- c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)
v1 <- as.vector(df1[2, ])
v2 <- c(0, 1, 1, 0)

######### working code

> sum(colSums(v1))
[1] 2

> sum(colSums(df1))
[1] 4
```

Comment: Works like a champ. `sum(colSums(df[ ,651:8500]))` takes care of all the list and `$` problems.

Answer (score 0):

`sum` is only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables. If we look at the patterns we see that `sum` fails at, `data.frame`s, i.e. listed logical objects (`$`).

```
str(v0) # works fine
# logi [1:4] FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE

# compare:
str(as.data.frame(v0))
# 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  1 variable:
#  $ v0: logi  FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE

str(v1) # fails
# 'data.frame': 1 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ aa: logi FALSE
# $ bb: logi TRUE
# $ cc: logi TRUE
# $ dd: logi FALSE

str(v2) # works fine
# num [1:4] 0 1 1 0

str(df1) # fails
# 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ aa: logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# $ bb: logi  FALSE TRUE TRUE FALSE
# $ cc: logi  FALSE TRUE TRUE FALSE
# $ dd: logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

str(df2) # works fine
# 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ ww: num  0 0 0 0
# $ xx: num  0 1 1 0
# $ yy: num  0 1 1 0
# $ zz: num  0 0 0 0
```

When we `unlist` them, it works fine.

```
str(v1) # fails
sum(unlist(v1)) # works fine
# [1] 2

str(df1) # fails
sum(unlist(df1)) # works fine
# [1] 4
```

Instead of `unlist` we also could convert the `data.frame`s `as.matrix` before `sum`, just get rid of the list structure.

```
sum(as.matrix(v1))
# [1] 2
sum(as.matrix(df1))
# [1] 4
```

Or even shorter...

```
sum(t(t(v1)))
# [1] 2
sum(t(t(df1)))
# [1] 4
```

...

```
sum(!(v1))
# [1] 2

sum(!!(df1))
# [1] 4
```

#### Edit

To apply on `data.frame`s like such

```
df1
#   a b    l1   l2    l3
# 1 t z  TRUE TRUE  TRUE
# 2 b a FALSE TRUE  TRUE
# 3 h j FALSE TRUE FALSE
# 4 c x  TRUE TRUE  TRUE

str(df1)
# 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  5 variables:
#  $ a : Factor w/ 4 levels "b","d","e","x": 3 2 1 4
#  $ b : Factor w/ 4 levels "c","r","w","x": 2 1 4 3
#  $ l1: logi  FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
#  $ l2: logi  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
#  $ l3: logi  FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE
```

we could `sum` up rectangles like so

```
sum(!!df1[3:5])
sum(!!df1[sapply(df1, is.logical)])  # or, allocating logical columns automatically 
# [1] 8
sum(!!df1[3:4, 4:5])  # or, sub-rectangles
# [1] 3
```

***Data***

```
df1 <- structure(list(a = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("b", 
"d", "e", "x"), class = "factor"), b = structure(c(2L, 1L, 4L, 
3L), .Label = c("c", "r", "w", "x"), class = "factor"), l1 = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE), l2 = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), l3 = c(FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Thank you jay.sf.  My dataframe has other columns of character data, so going to a matrix doesn't work.  And there are four columns *of lists* -- an unfortunate relic of the Excel spreadsheet from which the data came.  I am unlisting them observation by observation.  They are populating the sparse logical region of the dataframe. When I'm done, I'll unlist the whole dataframe as you suggest. I am eternally grateful to you.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're really dealing with list-inside-list objects order rather usually vectors inside lists. I made an example in an edit to my question of how I think your data frame might look like, and of how to get sums of _whole rectangles_, not columns. If you need column-wise sums, you probably need `colSums` as @julian-hn proposes.